# Access to Path Denied Error

Tags: c#

I have a program that needs to delete a full directory but I get the `Access to path denied` error. I give full access to everyone, but it hasn't helped.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm");
    string lowDir = "";
    if (label1.Text == comboBox1.Text)
    {
        try
        {
            if (System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(txpath1.Text).Length != 0)
            {
                try
                {
                    var folders = Directory.GetDirectories(@"" + txpath1.Text);
                    DateTime lastLow = DateTime.Now;

                    foreach (string subdir in Directory.GetDirectories(@"" + txpath1.Text))
                    {
                        DirectoryInfo fi1 = new DirectoryInfo(subdir);
                        fi1.Refresh();
                        DateTime created = fi1.LastWriteTime;
                        if (created < lastLow)
                        {
                            lowDir = subdir;
                            lastLow = created;
                        }
                    }
                    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"" + lowDir);
                    Directory.Delete(@"" + lowDir, true);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    this.btStop.PerformClick();
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message+"\nEzért a program leállt.");
                }
                finally
                {
                    timer1.Stop();
                    timer2.Start();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                this.btStop.PerformClick();
                MessageBox.Show("A megadott elérési útvonalon nem találhatóak fájlok a művelet(ek)hez!");
            }
        }
        catch (DirectoryNotFoundException)
        {
            btStop.PerformClick();
            MessageBox.Show("Hibás útvonala(kat)t adtál meg!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you checking that the directory is empty before trying to delete it? And make sure the directory isn't read only

Comment: I'm not sure you are correctly escaping `txpath1.Text`.

Comment: Josh, Nope i did'nt check it now, after i can make it work, i will. The directory is not empty, usually i am getting this error when the directory contains mp3,mp4, or exe file. If i place a simple pdf file into that directory i don't get this error.

Comment: Josh, I *think* that's what the second argument (`true`) is, in the `.Delete()` method (to delete recursive). @user1666620, shouldn't C# escape this string when it's read out, anyway?

Comment: btw: why do you call `GetDirectories()` for `txpath1.Text` _three times_? Cache the result in `folders` at the first call and use it.

Comment: Whats with the @""+txpath1.Text ?

Comment: Why on earth are you using a verbatim empty string as part of your arguments? Why don't you just use the variable itself...?

Comment: On which line do you get the error? Maybe you can check that the path exists before you try to delete it, and throw an exception if it doesn't exist?

Comment: Could you tell us what line it is getting the exception? Stick at breakpoint in and step through with the debugger to see where it skips to your `catch` block. Also, could you maybe quote the actual error in your OP?

Comment: Ian R. O'Brien, i got the error at this catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            this.btStop.PerformClick();
                            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message+"\nEzért a program leállt.");
                        }

Comment: @celodir - That's because you've got a try/catch and it won't throw an unhandled exception with the info box you might normally see - step through with the debugger, like I suggested; and let us know which line it jumps to the `catch` block from

Comment: @Geoff James, it said line 75
Directory.Delete(@"" + lowDir, true);

Comment: OK, great. Could you include this in your OP, and could you also give the exact error details you are seeing? Could you also post the value of `lowDir`, when it reaches line 75 (before it throws the exception)?

Comment: @celodir You must loop directories to get files using [DirectoryInfo.GetFiles()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4cyf24ss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), delete files using [FileInfo.Delete()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and finally delete the directory.

Comment: @Geoff James, here's the error: http://imgur.com/a/VV9wj , and lowDir contais a good path i tested it before

Comment: Deleting directories is in general a hazardous affair.  Too many programs tend to be interested in a directory.  Like anti-malware.  Or a process that uses the directory as its Environment.CurrentDirectory.  Or a FileSystemWatcher.  Or something as basic as using Explorer to check if your program works.  It will delete okay the first time you run it.  But the directory cannot disappear from the file system until everybody stops being interested.  If you run your program again then it will fail this way.  Moving it to the recycle bin is a good alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use `Directory.Delete(path, true)` to delete recursively. If that doesn't work then it is likely to be a malformed path.